# Dividing migrated Silverlight to HTML application into NPM modules

Tags: javascript

We need to move a large application from Silverlight over to HTML.
The application will have a client and server part.

Because of the size of the application, I thought it might be worth dividing some of the functionality into NPM modules, that way if I require it on the server side, I can, and if I want to use it on the client (using aurelia) I can do that through jspm.

From a reusability of modularized JS perspective, would you reckon that using NPM is the best approach to maintain a versioned reusable stack or are there other ways of dealing with this?

Comment: Yes. If you have shared code, put it in a library. Unfortunately, questions like this are too broad (and opinion-based) for the SO format. You might be better off on one of the less-concrete programming SE sites.

Answer (score 1):

Modularized code is definitely the way to go, I don't see any issue with using NPM as a versioned repo to deal with this especially as the code grows and is used by more and more people, however another approach might be using the githubs version tags, this might be a simpler solution as well (or atleast keeping everything in once place)